# remove id from selection many to many via ORM

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, many-to-many, left-join

i have table

[many-to-many table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2QCO.jpg)

and i have part of orm query builder

```
$posts = $posts->leftJoin('mh_posts_params','mh_posts.id', '=', 'mh_posts_params.post_id')
                            ->whereRaw('mh_posts_params.param_id <> ? OR mh_posts_params.param_id IS NULL', [$query->param__not_in()]);
```

My task is to completely remove from selection post_id if it has a very param_id, for example, 6.
Right now it removes post_id only if it has no more parameters, except 6.
Could i perform that using just ORM or even Pure SQL?

Answer (score 0):

just use `select()` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects)

```
$posts = $posts->leftJoin('mh_posts_params','mh_posts.id', '=', 'mh_posts_params.post_id')
               ->whereRaw('mh_posts_params.param_id <> ? OR mh_posts_params.param_id IS NULL', [$query->param__not_in()])
               ->select('name', 'other_filed', 'another_one' ...);
```